# Accept Formatting Changes in Word Headers, Footers and Main Document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using the following VBA code to accept all formatting changes in a document. Which lines would I need to add in order to accept the changes in the Header and Footer as well?

```
ActiveDocument.ShowRevisions = True
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFormatChanges = True
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowComments = False
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowInsertionsAndDeletions = False
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowInkAnnotations = False
ActiveDocument.AcceptAllRevisionsShown
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowComments = True
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowInsertionsAndDeletions = True
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFormatChanges = True
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ShowInkAnnotations = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

Works for all `Headers` and `Footers` and the `Main Document`.

```
 ActiveDocument.AcceptAllRevisions
```

Option 2

This will only `Accept` the revisions in the current viewable seciton of the `Document`.:

```
 ActiveDocument.Revisions.AcceptAll
```

What you can then Add before is something like:

```
'Opening the Header
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
```

Just run through the various `wdSeek` Options to go through the various sections if you want to look at specific revisions.

You can also run a script on each revision using a `Do` or `For` `Loop` with:

`ActiveDocument.Revisions.Item(x)`