# VBA Word - Conditionally Accept Changes in Headers and Footers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm scripting a Sub that cleans up a 'Tracked Changes' document due to *varying* levels of MS-Word proficiencies across our Tech-Writing and Eng Review teams.

Basically off the back of Document_Open event, I loop thru all the *StoryRanges* checking the *Revision.Type* and either *Accept* or *Do Nothing* based upon the enumerated value (.Type <> 1, 2 or 9) of the change.  I also do this across both *Headers* and *Footers* in the document too.

What's annoying me is that it will work across the Main Body of the document but I can't selectively accept any changes in the Header or Footer.

```
'Public Declarations
Public Sctn as Section
Public NewRevision as Revision
Public StorySect as Object
Public HdFt as HeaderFooter'

'Conditionlly Accept Changes in Document
    Public Sub Document_AcceptAll()

    On Error GoTo RevErr

    'Body
    For Each StorySect In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges 
        For Each NewRevision In ActiveDocument.Revisions
            Select Case ThisDocument.NewRevision.Type
                Case Is <> 1, 2 Or 9    '1: wdRevisionInsert  2: wdRevisionDelete  9: wdRevisionReplace
                    ThisDocument.NewRevision.Accept

                Case Else

            End Select

        Next NewRevision
    Next StorySect '<<

    'Header & Footers
    With ActiveDocument
        'Loop thru all Sections
        For Each Sctn In .Sections
            'Loop thru all Headers in Section
            For Each HdFt In Sctn.Headers
                With HdFt
                    For Each NewRevision In ActiveDocument.Revisions                            
                        Select Case ThisDocument.NewRevision.Type
                            Case Is <> 1, 2 Or 9    '1: wdRevisionInsert  2: wdRevisionDelete  9: wdRevisionReplace
                                ThisDocument.NewRevision.Accept
                            Case Else
                        End Select
                    Next NewRevision
                End With
            Next HdFt

            'Loop thru all Footers in Section
            For Each HdFt In Sctn.Footers
                With HdFt
                    For Each NewRevision In ActiveDocument.Revisions
                        Select Case ThisDocument.NewRevision.Type
                            Case Is <> 1, 2 Or 9    '1: wdRevisionInsert  2: wdRevisionDelete  9: wdRevisionReplace
                                ThisDocument.NewRevision.Accept
                            Case Else
                        End Select
                        Next NewRevision
                  End With    
            Next HdFt

        Next Sctn
    End With

lbl_Exit:
        Exit Sub
RevErr:
        If Err.Number <> 5852 Then
            Err.Clear
            GoTo lbl_Exit
        Else
            Err.Clear
            Resume
        End If
    End Sub
```

A simple solution would be just ignore it until Final Publication and Run an AcceptAll sub but then I loose the Change Bars and I don't think I could get a repeatable result if the team were tasked to manually add the Change Bars.

There seems to be another approach, have a SeekView loop against each Section and then nest the conditional Revision.Type but it seems like it is excessive for this application.

Any other approaches would be greatly appreciated, please bear in mind that the number of sections will vary between document instances.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrevisiontype

[Accept Formatting Changes in Word Headers, Footers and Main Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410229/accept-formatting-changes-in-word-headers-footers-and-main-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code shown is not picking up any revisions in the headers/footers is because, ideally, `Revisions` should be queried *on a Range*, not just on `ActiveDocument` or `Header` or `Footer`. The first case appears to be working for you, at least on the documents being tested, although I'd expect it to miss any revisions in text boxes.

Also, it should be possible to pick up the headers and footers by looping `StoryRanges`. See the last example in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.storyranges). What the code shown in the question is missing is using `NextStoryRange` in a loop.

The following code snippet demontrates both suggestions. The `Revisions` are queried on the `StoryRange` and the code loops *all* `StoryRanges` in the document. (Note that "in the real world" I'd probably put the code that repeats inside the loop in a separate procedure and call that procedure in both places, rather than duplicating all the code.)

```
Public Sub Document_AcceptAll()

'Public Declarations
    Dim Sctn As Section
    Dim NewRevision As Revision
    Dim StorySect As Word.Range
    Dim HdFt As HeaderFooter

    On Error GoTo RevErr

    For Each StorySect In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        'Debug.Print StorySect.StoryType
        For Each NewRevision In StorySect.Revisions
            Select Case NewRevision.Type
                Case Is <> 1, 2 Or 9    '1: wdRevisionInsert  2: wdRevisionDelete  9: wdRevisionReplace
                    NewRevision.Accept

                Case Else

            End Select

        Next NewRevision
        Do While Not (StorySect.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
            Set StorySect = StorySect.NextStoryRange

            For Each NewRevision In StorySect.Revisions
                Select Case NewRevision.Type
                    Case Is <> 1, 2 Or 9    '1: wdRevisionInsert  2: wdRevisionDelete  9: wdRevisionReplace
                        NewRevision.Accept

                    Case Else

                End Select

            Next NewRevision
        Loop
        Next StorySect '<<

lbl_Exit:
        Exit Sub
RevErr:
        If Err.Number <> 5852 Then
            Err.Clear
            GoTo lbl_Exit
        Else
            Err.Clear
            Resume
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, **thank you Cindy**.  I started looping thru WdSeekViews and it got messy as some sections had differing (fist page, odd/even) header / footer that the preceeding section...  This is alot cleaner.  Thansk Again

Comment: @DangerDraper You're welcome :-) `SeekView` is very unreliable to work with... and also causes massive screen flicker. Unfortunately, it's what the macro recorder provides <sigh> Glad I could point you at how to work with Ranges!